# Identify the student details based on their percentage using python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe, url-rewriting

I have two excels, Excel1 has list of students with overall percentage and Excel2 has scores of individual subjects of those students, Now I am filtering the students who's percentage is <95 and taking the name of the student to Excel2 to find the subject scores. i have to automate this process using python any syntax would be helpful.

Comment: Name Percentage
A 98
B 95
C 78
D 90
E 96
F 90

Comment: Name Subject Marks
C Maths 90
C Science 70
C English 95
D Social 80
D Science 80
D Maths 95

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want to add more details to your question please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55929627/edit) button instead of using [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Comments should be used for asking for more information or for suggesting improvements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask